# Equivalent mouse direction detection function in Javascript from jQuery

Tags: javascript, detect, mousemove, direction

How this mouse direction detection would be converted to pure JavaScript?

Question about my logic: Hold the first coordinates in a var and then repeatedly compare the current coordinates with previous one. Is this the best logic for such detection?

http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/7pBE7/5/

```
(function ($) {
var options = {};
var oldx = 0;
var direction = "";
var stop_timeout = false;
var stop_check_time = 150;
$.mousedirection = function (opts) {
    var defaults = {};
    options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
    $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
        var activeElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (e.pageX > oldx) {
            direction = "right";
        } else if (e.pageX < oldx) {
            direction = "left";
        }

        clearTimeout(stop_timeout);
        stop_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            direction = "stop";
            $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
            $(activeElement).trigger({
                type: "mousedirection",
                direction: direction
            });
        }, stop_check_time);

        $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
        $(activeElement).trigger({
            type: "mousedirection",
            direction: direction
        });
        oldx = e.pageX;
    });
}
})(jQuery)

$(function () {
$.mousedirection();
$(".container").bind("mousedirection", function (e) {
    $(this).html("Mouse Direction: <b>" + e.direction + "</b>");
});
});
```